# Regular expression for minimum of 10 characters and include 1 numeral and one capital letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate a string using jQuery.match() function. String must contain

1. Minimum of 10 characters.
2. Must contains atleast one numeral.
3. Must contain atleast one capital letter.

How can I do that? Can anyone show me the regular expression to do that?

I am already have this:

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

but it is validating like this only, allow atleast one special character, one uppercase, one lowercase(in any order).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not strictly conforming to the length restriction, because you haven't done it correctly. The first look-ahead - `(?=.{8,})`, is just testing for string with minimum length `8`. Remember, since the look-arounds are 0-length assertions, the look-aheads after `.{8,0}` are not consuming any character at all.

In fact, you can remove that first look-ahead, and simply use that quantifier at the end while matching.

Try this regex:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{10,}$
```

Break up:

```
^
(?=.*[A-Z])  # At least an uppercase alphabet
(?=.*[0-9])  # At least a numeral
.{10,}       # Any character 10 or more times 
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you got that regex; it seems to have been taken somewhere...

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
     ^^^^      ^^^^^      ^^^^^      ^--------^
      1          2          3            4
```

1. Makes sure there's at least 8 characters
2. Makes sure there's lowercase characters
3. Makes sure there's uppercase characters
4. Makes sure there are those special characters.

To make a regex to your requirements, do some changes:

```
^(?=.{10})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
     ^^^^      ^^^^^      ^^^^^
      1          2          3
```

1. Makes sure there's at least 10 characters
2. Makes sure there's at least a number.
3. Makes sure there's at least an uppercase letter.

You can make it a bit shorter using:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^                   # Start of group
    (?=.*\d)        #   must contain at least one digit
    (?=.*[A-Z])     #   must contain at least one uppercase character
       .            #   match anything with previous condition checking
         {10,}      #   length at least 10 characters
$                   # End of group
```

i.e.:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}$
```

Source:

- [Password matching expression](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/)

Comment: Lose the capture and add anchors. +1 for using `\d`